# How can I selectively add query parameters in redirect_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application, the `session` hash can contain the keys `sort` and `ratings` (in addition to `_csrf_token` and `session_id`), depending on what action a user takes. That is, it can contain both of them, either one of them, or neither, depending on what a user does.

Now, I wish to call `redirect_to` in my application and, at the same time, restore any session information (`sort` or `ratings`) the user may have provided.

To do this, I want to insert whatever key-value `session` has currently got stored (out of `sort` and `ratings`) as query parameters in my call to `redirect_to`. So, the path might look something like `/movies?sort=...&ratings=...`.

I don't know how to write the logic for this. How can I do this? And how do I go about selectively inserting query parameters while calling `redirect_to`? Is it even possible to do this?

*Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First just compose a hash containing the parameters you want - for example:

```ruby
opts = session.slice(:sort, :ratings)
              .merge(params.slice(:sort, :ratings))
              .compact_blank
```

This example would contain the keys `:sort, :ratings` with the same keys from the parameters merged on top (taking priority).

You can then pass the hash to the desired path helper:

```ruby
redirect_to foos_path(**opts)
```

You can either just pass a trailing hash option or use the `params` option to explitly set the query string:

```
irb(main):007:0> app.root_path(**{ sort: 'backwards' })
=> "/?sort=backwards"
irb(main):008:0> app.root_path(params: { ratings: 'XX' })
=> "/?ratings=XX"
irb(main):009:0> app.root_path(params: { })
=> "/"
```

An empty hash will be ignored.

If your calling `redirect_to` with a hash instead of a string you can add query string parameters with the `params:` key:

```
redirect_to { action: :foo, params: opts }
```

If you're working with an arbitrary given URL/path and want to manipulate the query string parameters you can use the URI module together with the utilities provided by Rack and ActiveSupport for converting query strings to hashes and vice versa:

```
uri = URI.parse('/foo?bar=1&baz=2&boo=3')
parsed_query = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(uri.query)
uri.query = parsed_query.except("baz").merge(x: 5).to_query 
puts uri.to_s # => "/foo?bar=1&boo=3&x=5"
```

Comment: Using `**` isn't actually required since the path helpers use the old style `options = {}` as a positional argument instead of real keyword arguments. It does however make the code future proof if this were to change.